# get package uninstallation notification in android

Tags: android

folks,

i have one security application in which i want the notification where package is
     uninstalled by user perform some action on that event
     please give me some solution

Thanks

Comment: have you done code for the uninstallation?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to monitor application installations or uninstallations, you may want to register a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for the actions `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED`, `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` and so on (see the full list in the [Intent class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) under "Standard Broadcast Actions"). You'll get supplied with the packagename of the app that was uninstalled in the intents data.

If you want to perform an action when your own app gets uninstalled: Thats not possible at the moment.